# SQL limit total vs limit column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where there are multiple events that happen within multiple* years. I'd like to return 5 total results (LIMIT 5), however I just wan't to return one of the events per year. How would this be done?

```
database table
2001 - something happened
1998 - something else happened
2001 - something more exciting happened
2003 - something friggen cool happened
1998 - something else happened the coolest thing ever

query returns
2001 - something happened
1998 - something else happened
2003 - something friggen cool happened
```

Comment: "....however I just wan't to return one of the events per year...." which event?

Comment: sounds like a group by year(eventdate) to me, but who can say without seeing the table schema

Comment: year is just an example, I might need it to be an id or anything. I updated my posting, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you need to group your results by year, but we need to know whick event you need so you can set aggregate function.

**UPDATE**
so ....

```
SELECT event FROM table GROUP BY year ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
```

but, in case of year 2001, which one you need?

Comment: All events, is events a bad word to use? I literally mean an event that happend that year. I updated my posting, does it make more sense now?

Comment: thanks for telling me about `group by` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp